# Can't delete node from node list

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list, delete-operator, function-definition

I have a little problem which occurs after trying to execute function `delete_all()`. Any idea why Visual Studio is throwing me an error:

> Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap, instruction __debugbreak() or something similar

Everything works perfect until I want to execute this function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string name = "n1";
    node* prev = NULL;
    node* next = NULL;
};

node* add(node* first, string name) {
    if (first == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    node* nowy = new node;

    if (first->next == NULL) {
        nowy->prev = first;
        first->next = nowy;
    }
    else {
        while (first->next != NULL) {
            first = first->next;
        }
        nowy->prev = first;
        first->next = nowy;
    }

    nowy->name = name;

    return nowy;
}

void writeout(node* first) {
    if (first == NULL) cout << "first = NULL";

    while (first->next != NULL) {
        cout << first->name;
        cout << "\n";
        first = first->next;
    }

    if (first->next == NULL) {
        cout << first->name;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void delete_all(node* first) {
    node* temp;
    while (first != NULL) {
        temp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    node n1;

    add(&n1, "n2");
    add(&n1, "n3");

    writeout(&n1);

    delete_all(&n1);
}
```

Comment: Is this any help: https://godbolt.org/z/8raxfzfra ? If not, discuss with your rubber duck what happens when you `delete` `node n1;`

Comment: Keep in mind, you can only `delete` that which had been `new`.

Comment: @user4581301 Let's say now i know error more specific.

Comment: @Eljay I have it in mind. Still everything should be fine.

Comment: When did you `new` the `node n1;`?

Comment: @Eljay Ahh my bad, I read your comment wrong

Comment: Even if you removed the delete_add(&n1); the code:  `add(&n1, "n2");   add(&n1, "n3");` would not work in correctly. You have a single node `n1` doing `&n1` will return the same address for the lifetime of the `n1` variable. Your code attempts to put this same node in the list 2 times pointing to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared an object in `main()` with automatic storage duration as the first node of the list:

```
node n1;
```

You may not destroy it using the `delete` operator.

Using your approach of the list implementation, you could define the function `delete_all()` the following way:

```
void delete_all(node* first) 
{
    if ( first != nullptr )
    {
        while ( first->next != nullptr ) 
        {
            node *temp = first->next;
            first->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
}
```

But, it will be much better if initially in `main()`, you declared a pointer to a `node`. In this case, you will need to update the functions.

Comment: Ok, now it works with other nodes, but how can i delete the first one if not by `delete` ?

Comment: @Eldzej02 You can't. It's an automatic variable. It's destruction is automatically managed. As soon as it goes out of scope, it's toast.

Comment: @Eldzej02 As it has automatic storage duration then it will be deleted automatically after exiting the code block where it is defined. Otherwise see my appended answer how you should define a list in main.

Comment: Having the code treat the 1st node specially (ie, not `new`'ed) vs the remaining nodes (ie, `new`'ed) is really not a good design choice.

Comment: For example, if future code inserts nodes at the beginning you'll lose which was the automatic allocation. Best to never mix the two types.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `delete_all()` is fine, but you are passing it a pointer to a `node` instance that was not created with `new`, so `delete`'ing that node is *undefined behavior*.  *ALL* of your node instances should be created dynamically, including the 1st node.

As such, your `add()` function should be updated to *not* blindly return without creating a new `node` instance if `first` is initially `NULL`.  You should instead update the caller's `node*` pointer to point at the new `node` that was created.

Also, `writout()` has *undefined behavior* if `first` is `NULL`, because you are *unconditionally* accessing `first->next` whether `first` is `NULL` or not.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string name = "n1";
    node* prev = nullptr;
    node* next = nullptr;
};

node* add(node* &first, string name) {
    if (!first) {
        first = new node{name};
        return first;
    }
    else {
        node *prev = first;
        while (prev->next) {
            prev = prev->next;
        }
        prev->next = new node{name, prev};
        return prev->next;
    }
}

/* alternatively:

node* add(node* &first, string name) {
    node **nowy = &first, *prev = nullptr;
    while (*nowy) {
        prev = *nowy;
        nowy = &(prev->next);
    }
    *nowy = new node{name, prev};
    return *nowy;
}

*/

void writeout(node* first) {
    if (!first) {
        cout << "first = NULL";
    }
    else {
        do {
            cout << first->name;
            first = first->next;
            if (first) cout << '\n';
        }
        while (first);
    }
}

void delete_all(node* first) {
    node* temp;
    while (first) {
        temp = first->next;
        delete first;
        first = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{   
    node* n1 = nullptr;

    add(n1, "n2");
    add(n1, "n3");

    writeout(n1);

    delete_all(n1);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
...

node* add(node* first, string name) {
    if (!first) {
        return new node{name};
    }
    else {
        while (first->next) {
            first = first->next;
        }
        first->next = new node{name, first};
        return first->next;
    }
}

/* alternatively

node* add(node* first, string name) {
    // same as node** further above ...
}

*/

...

int main()
{   
    node* n1 = add(nullptr, "n2");
    add(n1, "n3");

    ...

    delete_all(n1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I appreciate it.